# Is it more expensive to swap objects or primitives in java?

Tags: java, object, primitive

Say I have an array of some comparable objects. For convenience, think Integer. But really it could be some made up data type such as Car or Stuff. Say further that I need to find the extremum. Is it cheaper to swap the indices? the objects? or it does not matter? In other words is example A or example B cheaper

**Example A**

```
int least = 0;
for(int i=1; i<objects.length;i++)
  if(objects[i].isLessThan(objects[least)) least= i;
```

**Example B**

```
Stuff least = objects[0];
for(int i=1; i<objects.length;i++)
  if(objects[i].isLessThan(objects[least)) least= objects[i];
```

Comment: It should be the same. Swapping an integer value or a memory address should be pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Your code snippets need fixing. The array access `objects[least` is missing a closing square bracket, an in example B, you should replace `objects[least` with just `least`.

Comment: By the way, this is the sort of microoptimization that's not even worth thinking about unless you have a demonstrated performance problem right there.

Comment: @chrylis *If* a particular approach is always faster, or never slower and sometimes faster, than another approach, *and* there are not other drawbacks (such as poor readability), why not make the faster one the idiom that you always use? That said, I don't really think that this is the case here, but it's worth asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the same. If you hadn't done an access to `objects[i]` first to perform the comparison, then latency introduced because of memory access outside CPU caches could be an issue, but since you already accessed `objects[i]`, this is not likely to be a problem.

In really large arrays, greater than the page size of the cache, swapping the objects may be faster since you don't need to retrieve `objects[least]` for every comparison, but this is conjecture.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, every variable is either of primitive or of reference type (those of type `Car` merely hold a reference to the `Car` instance). That is, all variables are at most 64 bits large and may be assigned in a single cpu instruction. Long story short: it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

A reference in java, which is what you would be copying if you were to copy an object, is 32 bits on a 32 bit machine, or 64 bits on a 64 bit machine.

A primitive, on the other hand, depends on which kind. A byte, for example, is [8 bits wheras an integer is 32](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) So copying an integer around would cost just as much (or half as much on a 64 bit machine) copying time as a pointer.

In the end, it doesn't *really* matter, since you're only copying a reference, and not the data pointed to.

Comment: A Java reference is a reference, and the size is completely up to the JVM implementer. In particular, HotSpot uses compressed OOPs to store most references in 32 bits. Additionally, while the Java language treats bytes as if they only had 8 bits, all JVM words are 32 bits wide.